# Power BI : how to create measure that refer other measure (DAX)

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, data-analysis, measure

i try to create a matrix visual with measure as column and the KPI as row.
the issue is occur when the measure should accommodate each KPI calculation, so i think that create a measure that refer other measure(each KPI calculation) is the solution. please find the detail on below your advise would be greatly appreciated. thank you in advance

Here is the visual expectation

[image]

Here is the data that i prepare

[image]

this is one the KPI measure. that i would like to call/ refer on my "Column" Measure

```
LI MTD LY SOH Days DL MockUp = 

var SOHDaysCPD = CALCULATE(SUM('DataLake KPI Summary'[MTD Value]),ALL(Dim_Date[Date]),
        'DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]="SOH (days)",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Division]="Consumer Products",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Year]=2022
    )
var SOHDaysPPD = CALCULATE(SUM('DataLake KPI Summary'[MTD Value]),ALL(Dim_Date[Date]),
        'DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]="SOH (days)",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Division]="Professional Products",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Year]=2022
    )
var SOHDaysLLD = CALCULATE(SUM('DataLake KPI Summary'[MTD Value]),ALL(Dim_Date[Date]),
        'DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]="SOH (days)",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Division]="L'Oreal Luxe",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Year]=2022
    )
var SOHDaysACD = CALCULATE(SUM('DataLake KPI Summary'[MTD Value]),ALL(Dim_Date[Date]),
        'DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]="SOH (days)",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Division]="Active Cosmetics",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Year]=2022
    )
var SOHValueLI = CALCULATE(SUM('DataLake KPI Summary'[MTD Value]),ALL(Dim_Date[Date]),
        'DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]="B2B SOH (M)",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Year]=2022
    )
var SOHValueCPD = CALCULATE(SUM('DataLake KPI Summary'[MTD Value]),ALL(Dim_Date[Date]),
        'DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]="B2B SOH (M)",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Division]="Consumer Products",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Year]=2022
    )
var SOHValuePPD = CALCULATE(SUM('DataLake KPI Summary'[MTD Value]),ALL(Dim_Date[Date]),
        'DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]="B2B SOH (M)",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Division]="Professional Products",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Year]=2022
    )
var SOHValueLLD = CALCULATE(SUM('DataLake KPI Summary'[MTD Value]),ALL(Dim_Date[Date]),
        'DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]="B2B SOH (M)",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Division]="L'Oreal Luxe",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Year]=2022
    )
var SOHValueACD = CALCULATE(SUM('DataLake KPI Summary'[MTD Value]),ALL(Dim_Date[Date]),
        'DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]="B2B SOH (M)",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Division]="Active Cosmetics",'DataLake KPI Summary'[Year]=2022
    )

var CPD = SOHValueCPD / SOHDaysCPD
var PPD = SOHValuePPD / SOHDaysPPD
var LLD = SOHValueLLD / SOHDaysLLD
var ACD = SOHValueACD / SOHDaysACD

return
    SOHValueLI/(CPD+PPD+LLD+ACD)
```

this is the "Column" Measure that i expect could add some syntax formula that refer to KPI measure

```
MTD LY DL MockUp = 
var val = TOTALMTD(SUM('DataLake KPI Summary'[MTD Value]),DATEADD(Dim_Date[Date],-1,year))
var val1 =  TOTALMTD(AVERAGE('DataLake KPI Summary'[MTD Value]),DATEADD(Dim_Date[Date],-1,year))

return 
IF(SELECTEDVALUE('DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]) ="Service Rate (%)" || SELECTEDVALUE('DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]) ="SI FCA (M-3) (%)"|| SELECTEDVALUE('DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]) ="SI FCA (M-3) (%)"|| SELECTEDVALUE('DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]) ="SI FCA (M-3) (%)"|| SELECTEDVALUE('DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]) ="SI FCA Bias (%)"|| SELECTEDVALUE('DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]) ="SO FCA (M-3) (%)"|| SELECTEDVALUE('DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]) ="SO FCA Bias (%)"|| SELECTEDVALUE('DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]) ="CDC Country IQ rate (%)"|| SELECTEDVALUE('DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]) ="Avg. Total Inventory / CNS (%)"|| SELECTEDVALUE('DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]) ="EOM. Credit/CNS (%)"|| SELECTEDVALUE('DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]) ="Overdue / total credit (%)"|| SELECTEDVALUE('DataLake KPI Summary'[Cube]) ="Avg Overdue / total credit (%)",FORMAT( val1,"0.0%"),
SWITCH ( TRUE(),
        val > 1000, FORMAT ( val / 1000,"0.0" & "B" ),val))
```

Comment: https://www.sqlbi.com/calculation-groups/

Comment: thanks @RADO for the feedback, to be precise my intention was to create one column that could refer to different measure based on the row that selected.
your solution was grouping several measure into 1 and create several column. really appreciate if you could feedback with my requirement